# Vlookup with a named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable which takes the name of a workbook. I will be working through a list of these workbooks. For example,

```
dim unit_index as variant

unit_index = "unit_20444b_201608.xls"
```

I want to use a `vlookup` to return a value from the workbook assigned to `unit_index`. So when I enter the `vlookup` formula manually and record the macro I get the code below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],unit_20444b_201608.xls!alpha_lookup,2,FALSE)"
```

I want the workbook name to change dynamically so I want the code to look something like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],**unit_index**!alpha_lookup,2,FALSE)"
```

`alpha_lookup` is the named range in `unit_index`.

So the workbook name would change as `unit_index` is updated. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to try it like this...

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & unit_index & "!alpha_lookup,2,FALSE)"
```